# Adding attribute to master page usercontrol from content page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a usercontrol for header in the masterpage. I need to an attribute 'linkName' from some of the content pages. ie for some pages it should be
 `<uc1:AdminHeader ID="Adminheader1" runat="server" linkClass="adminHeaderSelected" link="manageData"></uc1:AdminHeader>` 
and in few other pages it should be
 `<uc1:AdminHeader ID="AdminHeader1" runat="server" linkName="adminusers"></uc1:AdminHeader>`

how can i acheive this througn content pages?

Comment: You want to set this property from ContentPage or you want to add a (non existing) property?

Comment: I want to add a non existing property

Comment: Try my [edited answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8816585/284240).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a public property `LinkName` to your MasterPage that get/set the UserControl's property.
Then you can set it from the page in the following way:

```
((MyMaster)this.Page.Master).LinkName = "adminusers";
```

Where `MyMaster` is the actual type of your MasterPage.

VB.NET:

```
DirectCast(Me.Page.Master, MyMaster).LinkName = "adminusers"
```

**Edit**: If you want to add an non-existing attribute at runtime:

Create a method `AddHeaderAttribute`:

```
public void AddHeaderAttribute(string key, string Value)
{
    Adminheader1.Attributes.Add(key, Value);
}
```

VB.NET

```
Public Sub AddHeaderAttribute(key As String, Value As String)
   Adminheader1.Attributes.Add(key, Value)
End Sub
```

Call this method in the way described above, for example

```
((MyMaster)this.Page.Master).AddHeaderAttribute("LinkName", "adminusers");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.attributes.aspx